# The time using 'Set date and time automatically' differs between OS X and iOS

Tags: macos, ios, timezone

On my OS X Mavericks my time is always a few minutes (about 4 minutes) ahead of my iOS 7.1.2 iPhone. Both devices are set to set the date and time automatically.

On my Mac I can choose from:

- Apple Americas/U.S. (time.apple.com.)
- Apple Asia (time.asia.apple.com.)
- Apple Europe (time.euro.apple.com.)

but these do not differ more than a second or so.

On my iPhone I can only choose 'Set Automatically'.

**Why is there a difference between both times? And which one is 'real'?**

Screenshot taken with a few seconds in between (believe me ;)
[image: osx time settings]
[image: iphone time settings]

Comment: Does my iPhone use a non-apple time server?

Comment: Can I resize my iPhone screenshot using this forums engine? (might be a valid discussion..)

Comment: As regards which one is real, I like the website at http://time.gov - I can work out timezone differences myself from that easily enough

Comment: @MarkSetchell, well the iPhone is right according to your clock. (btw, that site sucks horribly in obeying WWW etiquette)

Comment: Is it possible that Parallels is responsible for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone does not use NTP to synchronize its clock. It uses a feature of the cellular network. I can't tell you why your Mac's clock is off that far, but I suggest you use `nl.pool.ntp.org` instead of `time.euro.apple.com`.

Comment: Funny, using nl.pool.ntp.org will not change my time at all. This might be because my 'correction factor' is wrong. I have had issues with this because of Parallels...

Comment: Similar, but this worked: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119485/55028

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your `ntp.drift` file is something insane - check `/var/db/ntp.drift`, delete it if necessary, and restart (kill) `ntpd`.

Comment: I have no `/var/db/ntp.drift` on my OS X Mavericks. Strange, because I do have a /usr/sbin/ntpd -c /private/etc/ntp-restrict.conf -n -g -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -f /var/db/ntp.drift process running... And rebooting does not solve my issue, so I think killing ntpd doesn't either.

Comment: What qualifies as an insane value in this file?